# Entire function that decays faster than exponential on reciprocals of integers is $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is entire and $|f(1/n)|\le e^{-n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $f=0$.

My idea is to express $f$ as a power series centered at $0$ that converges on the entire complex plane, then look at 
$$\left|\sum a_k/ n^k \sum n^k/k!\right|\le 1$$
which requires $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left|\sum_{k = 0}^m \frac{a_k}{n^k}\frac{n^{m-k}}{(m-k)!}\right| = 0$, but then I get stuck. Could someone suggest a good way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $f \not\equiv 0$, then there are $c_k \ne 0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(z)| = \left|z^k(c_k + c_{k+1}z +\ldots)\right|\ge \dfrac{|c_k|}{2}|z|^k$ for $|z| < \delta$.